# How can i show these grey inlined Parameters in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am trying to show these Parameters if i call a function that has one parameter named Text
and if i call that function and enter the Text that should be assigned to my parameter but if i do that the parameter name should be automatically displayed next to the string that is assigned to the parameter on the right.

it looks like this now:

```
def change_text(text:str)
    print(text)

change_text("Hello World!")
```

but it should look like this:

```
def change_text(text:str)
    print(text)

change_text(text="Hello World!")
```

P.S the `text=` next to the "Hello World!" above is the grey name that should be automatically displayed.

i tried in the Setting and the JSON File in Visual Studio Code. But nothing worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable this setting by going to

Preferences -> Settings -> Editor -> Inlay Hints
[image]

and also enable for specific Python Language as well
[image]

As you can see the inlay hints are now enabled in a .py file
[image]